# Best way to include a large array of constants in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a Java app that has an array of 2.6 million values which never change.  What is the best way to initialize it?

The obvious answer is to put it in code - i.e. something like:

```
int[] BigArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3, <...>, 2599999, 2600000};
```

but I am under the impression that this violates some size limit.

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763422/large-amount-of-constants-in-java) that mentions key/value pairs in Properties, but that doesn't seem particularly intuitive - I don't see why I need to have each array entry saved as a key (for the array index) and a value; I should be able to have just the values in order.

The next best way appears to be having the data saved as a file, and then to load the file into the array (or use a List) on startup, with each value on its own line (yes, the line separators take up 2.6MB, but so would 2.6 million commas).  Is this a time-intensive way of doing it?

Comment: Are those the actual values, in order?  If so, you don't even need the array, because `BigArray[i]` is `i + 1`.  If you have `i`, just add `1`.

Comment: is it just ints? and if so are all of them present or do you skip some?

Comment: I don't think this is a universal truth, but if you have that many constants in your application then you're doing something wrong.

Comment: If they are all `int`s then you don't have to convert them to text, you can just write them (as `int`s) to a file and read them. You can also serialize objects, if those are objects.

Comment: No, thw array is not BigArray[N] = N for all N.  The intent is to map 2.6 million values to about 135,000 values, each of which has one of 10 values - and there are about 20 sets of these 135,000 values, which the user can select.  Having 20 sets of 2.6 million values would require the app to be 52 MB; 1 set of 2.6 million values and 20 of 130,000 uses only about 5.2 MB.

Comment: There is a limit to the size of an individual method, due to the (rather stupid) limits on the length of a branch.  But this limit does not apply to the `static` method --- it can be enormous (and often is, in some of the JDKs char table classes, eg).  So basically if you put the above initialization into `static` it might work.

Comment: I would say you store those values with a separator like : (colon) in a string. Then parse them whenever you need them. If its not coming in one string, it should surely come in a set of strings. As length of 2^31 - 1 seems large enough to store your amount of data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816142/strings-maximum-length-in-java-calling-length-method

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are trying to get an array of every int value up to 2.6M, just do this

```
    int[] bigArray = new int[2600000];
    for(int i = 0; i < 2600000; i++)
    {
        int j = i;
        bigArray[i] = j+1;
    }
```

The article you referenced was tagged Android development, so I don't know if you're developing for Android as this post is not tagged android, but this should work if you're doing what I think you're doing.